# NoReverseMatch after upgrading to Django 1.6 from 1.4

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Finally upgraded a project to 1.6 and now I'm having trouble with URLs and Class Based Views.

I have a form that starts like this:

`<form action="{{ project.get_absolute_url }}" method="post" id="editproject" >`

And the project model includes this:

```
@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return  ('project_url', (), {'slug': self.slug})
```

On trying to load the page I'll get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /teamslug1/projectslug1/teamid1/projectid1/
Reverse for 'project_url' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': u'projectslug1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<teamslug>[^\\.]+)/(?P<projectslug>[^\\.]+)/(?P<teamid>[^\\.]+)/(?P<projectid>[^\\.]+)/$']
```

If I wrap the form variable in quotes:

`<form action="{{ "project.get_absolute_url" }}" method="post" id="editproject" >`

It won't error out on loading but when I POST with the form it'll result in an url like this: `http://0.0.0.0:5000/teamslug1/projectslug1/teamid1/projectid1/project.get_absolute_url`, which doesn't exist.

Here's the urls.py info:

`url(r'^(?P<teamslug>[^\.]+)/(?P<projectslug>[^\.]+)/(?P<teamid>[^\.]+)/(?P<projectid>[^\.]+)/$', 'ideas.views.projects', name='project_url'),`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like a problem specific to Django 1.6 or class based views. The problem is that the `get_absolute_url` method doesn't match the URL pattern.

Firstly, wrapping the variable in quotes is definitely incorrect. Django treats it as a string, your browser treats it as a relative link, and posts the form to the wrong URL.

The `project_url` URL pattern has four keyword arguments but your `get_absolute_url` method only specifies `slug`, which isn't one of those arguments. I would expect your `get_absolute_url` method to look something like:

```
@permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return  ('project_url', (), {'teamslug': self.teamslug,
                                 'projectslug': self.projectslug,
                                 'projectid': self.projectid,
                                 'teamid ': self.teamid,
    })
```

Note that the docs recommend that you use `reverse` instead of the `permalink` decorator.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return  reverse('project_url', kwargs={'teamslug': self.teamslug,
                                           'projectslug': self.projectslug,
                                           'projectid': self.projectid,
                                           'teamid ': self.teamid,
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! Things seem to be working now I simplified the URL and switched over to `reverse`.